# Keras backend: starting interactive TF session

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When using Keras with TF backend, I can create a new TF session using `K.get_session()` as follows:

```
from keras import backend as K
tf_session = K.get_session()
```

Is there a similar function in Keras backend for starting an Interactive TF session? Can't find anything in the docs. Even `K.get_session()` is not documented, so I thought maybe I am missed it somewhere.

Comment: Is there a special reason to create such a session? Usually you don't need to care about that with keras.

Comment: @DanielMöller  I am trying to rewrite some TF code in Keras. I guess Keras is too high level for that application, since I am already calling the backend in almost every line.

Comment: You can simply use `import tensorflow as tf` and use the tensorflow functions inside either lambda or custom layers.

Comment: @DanielMöller thanks, I will try it

Comment: @MaxLawnboy did you find a solution? I am trying to use KFolds and it seems to fail because it is not an InteractiveSession.

Comment: @DanielMöller, could you please give an example.

Comment: I'm not sure about what the problem is, so I can't help. Would an interactive session be the eager mode? Usually I never touch sessions in keras, but I don't know exactly what the code is doing.

Comment: This shows the usage of lambda layers with custom functions. You can put any function from tensorflow inside `myFunc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886195/how-to-use-lambda-layer-in-keras --- But if the problem is KFolds, I have no idea if this is helpful.

Comment: @DanielMöller from https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/k_get_session.html I learned that I can do ```K.set_session(sess)```  and I was able to set the session to interactive. However the problem is still there. Guess something is wrong with KFolds...

Answer (score 0):

you can define your session by doing this

```
graph = tf.Graph() # Tensorflow graph
with graph.as_default():
    session = tf.Session() # Tensorflow session
    with session.as_default():
        model.load('model.h5')
        # or define your model or use predict or eval methods...
```

Like this you can create a customized session and graph for your Keras model.