# how to use merge in keras 2.0 with `mul` operator

Tags: python, merge, keras

I have the code for `keras 1.0`

```
from keras.layers import  merge

predict_vector = merge([a, b], mode = 'mul')
```

since the `merge` is gone, then what is the equivalent code for above `merge` in keras `2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [lambda-layer](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L565), which can fulfill your requirement. Here is an example

```
import keras.backend as K

def mulFun(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]
first = Dense( input_shape1 )(x1)
second = Dense( input_shape2 )(x2)
# perform  opration
Lambda(mulFun, output_shape)([first, second])
```

Here is [another-good-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886195/how-to-use-lambda-layer-in-keras) on using this.