# Piecewise activation function in tensorflow and broadcasting math operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, activation-function

I am trying to implement and test an activation function that I have read in a paper.

I am using Keras with tensorflow backend and I want to feed the activation function to the fit method of my model. Here is the mathematical form of the function:

[Piecewise Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvde6.jpg)

I have tried to implement this in two ways :

```
def function_1(x):

    cond1 = tf.greater(x , 2.0)
    cond2 = tf.logical_and(tf.less_equal(x, 2.0), tf.greater_equal(x, 0.0))
    cond3 = tf.logical_and(tf.less(x, 0.0), tf.greater_equal(x, -2.0))
    cond4 = tf.less(x, -2.0)

    y = tf.where(cond1, tf.constant(1.0) , tf.where(cond2,
    x - 0.25*tf.square(x), tf.where(cond3, x + 0.25*tf.square(x), 
    tf.where(cond4, tf.constant(-1.0), tf.constant(-1.0)))))

    return y

def function_2(x):

    cond1 = tf.greater(x , 2.0)
    cond2 = tf.logical_and(tf.less_equal(x, 2.0), tf.greater_equal(x, 0.0))
    cond3 = tf.logical_and(tf.less(x, 0.0), tf.greater_equal(x, -2.0))
    cond4 = tf.less(x, -2.0)

    y = tf.case({cond1: lambda x: tf.constant(1.0), cond2: lambda x: x - 
    0.25*tf.square(x), cond3: lambda x: x + 0.25*tf.square(x),
    cond4: lambda x: tf.constant(-1.0)}, exclusive = True)

    return y
```

In both cases I get the same kind of error :

InvalidArgumentError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 2 for 'dense_22/Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [?,5], [], [].

What is the correct way to to this and what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you compare a tensor with shape `[None, 5]` (rank 2) with a scaler (rank 0) which is not possible with [`tf.greater`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/greater) or [`tf.less`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/less). Instead, you can use `tf.math...` that support broadcasting.

Here is one possible solution to implement this function:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 5])

cond1 = tf.cast(tf.math.greater(x, 2.0), tf.float32)
cond2 = tf.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.less_equal(x, 2.0), tf.math.greater_equal(x, 0.0)), tf.float32)
cond3 = tf.cast(tf.math.logical_and(tf.math.less(x, 0.0), tf.math.greater_equal(x, -2.0)), tf.float32)
cond4 = tf.cast(tf.math.less(x, -2.0), tf.float32)

a = tf.math.multiply(cond1, 1.0)
b = tf.math.multiply(cond2, (x - tf.square(x) / 4))
c = tf.math.multiply(cond3, (x + tf.square(x) / 4))
d = tf.math.multiply(cond4, -1.0)

f = a + b + c + d

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(f, feed_dict={x: [[-1.0, -5, 1.5, -1.5, 5]]}))
```

Comment: Thanks.Problem Solved!
I didn't pay attention to broadcasting in tf.math functions

Answer (score 0):

You can try out `lambda` layer, which is very handy to add our custom layer or function in a network. Here is an example:

```
dense1 = Dense(dims)(input)   
act1 = Lambda(customFunc, output_shape)(dense1)

def customFunc(x):
    """-----operations----""""
    # final output y of shape defined as above in layer
    y = conditioned-output
    return y
```

Here is link for more [info](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L565) This is another useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886195/how-to-use-lambda-layer-in-keras), explained with example.